# How to add (upload file) to a ready form to the same controller, model and route? - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, forms, model, controller, upload

Currently I'm working on a form in Laravel 8 so I can get info from users so they can participate in a contest, the form is ready and linked to database as well,

My question here is:
How can I add one more field to the form so the users can upload files such as pdf,mp4, etc

This is the form:

1-Blade:

```
<form action="Form-1" method="POST" class="">
@csrf
<h1 style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" class="text-center">
  نموذج التقديم
  للشركات
</h1>
<br>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
    <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1">اسم البرنامج / المشروع</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input100 text-center" type="text" name="projectname1">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1">اسم المؤسسة</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input100 text-center" type="text" name="firmname1">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1">التعريف بالمؤسسة</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input100 text-center" type="text" name="firmdec1">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1">نوع المؤسسة</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input100 text-center" type="text" name="firmtype1">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1">مبررات المشاركة في الجائزة</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input100 text-center" type="text" name="why1">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1">الاسم الثلاثي لمسؤول الإتصال والتنسيق</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input100 text-center" type="text" name="fullname1">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1">العنوان</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input100 text-center" type="text" name="address1">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1">رقم الجوال</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input100 text-center" type="text" name="phone1">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1">البريد الإلكتروني</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input100 text-center" type="email" name="email1">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1">هل سبق لكم من قبل التقدم لجائزة ؟ نعم / لا</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input100 text-center" type="text" name="pb1">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1"> هل سبق لكم من قبل الفوز بجائزة ؟ نعم / لا</label>
    </div>
    <input class="input100 text-center" type="text" name="wb1">
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div class="text-center font-weight-bold">
    <label style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" for="projectname1">كيف عرفت عن الجائزة</label>
    </div>
    <textarea class="input100 text-center" type="text" name="how1" style="height: 200px;"></textarea>
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" class="text-center font-weight-bold"> الموافقة على الشروط وآلية التقديم
    <input type='checkbox' required>
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
  <div style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif; color:#695e4a" class="text-center font-weight-bold"> أشهد أن المعلومات المذكورة أعلاه صحيحة ومؤكدة
    <input type='checkbox' required>
    <span class="focus-input100"></span>
    <span class="symbol-input100">
    </span>
</div>
</div>





<div class="container-login100-form-btn">
    <button type="submit" style="font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;" class="login100-form-btn">
      <br>
        <br>
        تقديم النموذج
        
    </button>
    
</div>



<br>
        <br>
```

2-Controller:

```
$table= new Enquiry1Model;
    $table->projectname1=$req->projectname1;
    $table->firmname1=$req->firmname1;
    $table->firmdec1=$req->firmdec1;
    $table->firmtype1=$req->firmtype1;
    $table->why1=$req->why1;
    $table->fullname1=$req->fullname1;
    $table->address1=$req->address1;
    $table->phone1=$req->phone1;
    $table->email1=$req->email1;
    $table->pb1=$req->pb1;
    $table->wb1=$req->wb1;
    $table->how1=$req->how1;
    $table->save();
    return redirect('/Success');
```

3-Model:

```
class Enquiry1Model extends Model

use HasFactory;
public $table = "enquiry1";
```

4-Route:

```
Route::view('Form-1','enquiry1');
Route::post('Form-1',[Enquiry1Controller::class, 'addData']);
```

Comment: i edited the routes, it was the wrong ones

Answer (score 0):

You would add the input field as a file type as you normally would when adding this sort of thing to a form.

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

Now you would need to store the image on your server in order for it to be loaded later on. so to do this, you can add the following in your controller before you add the data to the database.

```
// Get the name of the original file
$file_name = $req->file->getClientOriginalName();

// This will place the file directly in the 'public' directory with the original file name
$req->file->move('', $file_name);

// This will place the file in the public/images directory with the original file name
$req->file->move('images', $file_name);
```

Next you will need to add the filename to the database within the user table under a new column. So create a new column name (e.g. file_name) for your Enquiry1 Model and then you can add the following to store the filename within the database.

```
$table->file_name = $file_name;
```

The above only allows you to add one file per user. If you want to give the ability for users to add more files then you will need to use a specific table to store filenames against each user and reference the user ID in the file table.